# Using a file's contents in a sed expression

Tags: bash, sed

I am looking to perform an operation with `sed` that appends to a specific part of a series of files like to:

```
sed -i "s/test:\n/&$(<test.file)/g" foo.txt
```

Is there a way I can take the output of a file or some BASH varaible and place it into sed for input into a file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Good question, I forgot to replace cat with BASH when I finished writing out the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^test:$/{r test.file
d}' foo.txt
```

Should do the trick.  Note that the literal newline after the filename is not necessary in all versions of sed, but is advisable.  The r command reads the contents of the named file.

Comment: Strictly, the caret isn't wanted, but there should be an ampersand added too.

Comment: I didn't notice the amersand.  That actually simplifies things a lot, since we can just drop the `d` command.